# Julia macro hygiene for vectors

Tags: julia, escaping, metaprogramming

I just stumbled upon a strange behaviour while working with macros in Julia. I want to escape all elements in a vector and approched this with the map function. When I store the result back in a vector, the escape function is seems not to be evaluated after the macro call, but when the output of the map function gets stored into variables, the expected behaviour can be seen.

Stored in the vector the elements look similar to a single escaped symbol.

```
input = [:a, :b]
escaped_input = map(x -> esc(x),input)
println(escaped_input) 
>>> Expr[:($(Expr(:escape, :a))), :($(Expr(:escape, :b)))]

println(esc(:a))
>>> :($(Expr(:escape, :a)))
```

But when the elements are accessed inside a macro in the quote, the escape function seems to not get executed:

```
a = 1
b = 2

macro escapeVector(testVec...)
    escapedVec = map(x -> esc(x), collect(testVec))
    quote
        map(x -> println(x), $escapedVec)
        println($escapedVec)
    end
end

macro escapeVars(testVec...)
    esc_a, esc_b = map(x -> esc(x), collect(testVec))
    quote
        println($esc_a)
        println($esc_b)
    end
end

@escapeVector a b
@escapeVars a b
```

This code produces the following output:

```
>>> $(Expr(:escape, :a))
>>> $(Expr(:escape, :b))
>>> Expr[:($(Expr(:escape, :a))), :($(Expr(:escape, :b)))]
>>> 1
>>> 2
```

Is there a way to trigger the escape inside the vector, so that the variables can be accessed or do I miss something obvious here?

Comment: You might be looking for `:([$(escaped_vec...)])`, to turn a vector of expressions into an expression with a vector.

Comment: I don't exactly get the question. Can you provided expected input/output examples for the macro you want to write? (It seems like you might have a misconception about what escaping is, though...)

Comment: @phipsgabler I have a module, where I have created some structs and with the macros I want to introduce a new syntax for assigning values. So a example call would be `@a varA -> varB varC `. The accessing of the required symbols in the input expressions works fine. The expected outcome would be that varA has a vector with varB and varC. As far as I understand I use esc() inside the macro to tell julia where to look for this variable, right?
And this works fine, if the variables are stored seperatly (as in @escapeVars), but not when they are inside a vector (as in @escapeVector)

Comment: @mcabbott I played around with this but could not get it working. Could you please explain your approach in more detail?

Comment: My reading is that this isn't an escaping problem at all, `[:(1+1), :(2+2)]` will give you the same problem. But you might be thinking something else, I don't know. Your macros return expressions which return `nothing`, but have side-effects, which presumably isn't what you really want, but adds another layer of potential confusion.

And, as Phil suggests, it's always a good idea to write out exactly what code you want the macro to produce, from what input. And then use `@macroexpand` to see whether it is producing this.

Comment: This might be true, but I find it very confusing, that the behaviour changes, once the expressions are stored in a vector...
Anyway I found a workaround by escaping the whole quote, which gives me the intended code, but I will further look into this in the future. So thank you so far!